# Opening a Microsoft Project file with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I'm trying to open a Microsoft Project file via VBA and then copy some ranges to an excel workbook. But i'm getting an error in my code:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

On that command: `Set mpp = myMPP.Application.FileOpen(FilenameMPP)`

```
Sub project2xCell()

 Set myMPP = CreateObject("Msproject.Application")
 Set myXLS = CreateObject("Excel.application")

 FilenameMPP = OpenFileDialogMPP() 'Function to browse to a Microsoft Project file
 FilenameExcel = OpenFileDialogXLS() 'Function to browse to a Excel Workbook

 myMPP.Visible = True
 Set mpp = myMPP.Application.FileOpen(FilenameMPP)
 Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FilenameExcel)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because the [documentation for the open call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.fileopenex) states that the return value for the function is a `Boolean`. You're attempting to assign a boolean to an object. Thus a type mismatch.

I strongly advise you to [enable `Option Explicit`](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html). This will help avoid some errors with your variables.

Additionally, you should consider using [early binding](http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2018/09/vba-referencing-and-early-binding-vs-late-binding/) (at least during your design and debugging phase of your development) to include the MS Project library reference.

```
Option Explicit

Sub project2xCell()
    Dim myMPP As MSProject.Application
    Set myMPP = CreateObject("Msproject.Application")
    myMPP.Visible = True

    Dim filenameMPP As String
    filenameMPP = OpenFileDialogMPP() 'Function to browse to a Microsoft Project file

    myMPP.FileOpenEx Name:=filenameMPP, ReadOnly:=True
    Set mpp = myMPP.ActiveProject

    '--- now you can work with your project

    myMPP.Quit
End Sub
```